# Can't access module settings (Devel module)

Tags: debugging

I have a module that's enabled and working, but the configuration options won't show.

The module in this case is Devel, which I've used on other sites with no problem.  In this site, whenever I click on 'configure' in the Devel module listing, it takes me to the configuration page, but without a Devel option.

I've cleared the cache and re-enabled multiple times. The module is definitely enabled because I can use functions like `ddebug_backtrace()`.

What else can I try?

**EDIT:**

I've uninstalled and re-installed the module, and still have no luck. I need an advice on how to trouble-shoot this.

Comment: I assume that you are using Drupal 7.8 and Devel 7.1.2? If not update the modules. Clearly something is wrong, you may want to unload Devel and reinstall. Please follow up on his post with what happens or doesn't :( .

Comment: Yes- those are the versions- re-installing now... I'll follow up in a sec

Comment: Uninstalled- reinstalled- nothing. Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: Try looking through the issues for Devel on Drupal.org? Please keep this post updated with anything you find. I'll return if I spot something. Your other post about the module staying on the list after uninstalling it made me laugh.  I had a similar problem. I forgot to mention that experience.

Answer (score 1):

I Think I figured out the culprit, if not the exact reason- I was getting “Allowed memory size” errors on common tasks like enabling modules, and once I remedied that my config screen showed up.

The memory error issue was addressed [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/allowed-memory-size-errors-on-common-tasks).